# WPF - How to capture when CTRL+SHIFT are pressed down?

Tags: wpf, keyboard, transparency, opacity

When the user clicks left CTRL+ left SHIFT I want to make the entire application translucent (like VS2008's intellisense drop-down). If I write my code on the KeyUp event I can capture both keys being pressed, but the transparency effect should only be active while the keys are pressed. When they are release the opacity should go back to 100%. The behavior I want is actually the KeyDown event, but I can't capture both keys on KeyDown, can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the static methods of the [`Keyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.aspx) class, specifically [`IsKeyDown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown.aspx) to check the state of the keys you're interested in.

On `KeyDown` you can use this to enable the translucency and on `KeyUp` you can disable the effect again. If you are at it, you could save the key's state yourself and act upon it.